# How to loop over globs in Fish shell?

Tags: shell, loops, fish

I'm trying to do a simple loop on a list of glob. In `bash` it will be

```
for requirement in "$fish_function_path"/__*; do
    source "$requirement";
done
```

What is the Fish equivalent?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

fish has different syntax than bash. You want

```
for requirement in "$fish_function_path"/__*
    source $requirement
end
```

See [for - perform a set of commands multiple times](http://fishshell.com/docs/current/commands.html#for) on official doc.